# How to secure json

Tags: php, json

So I have a main page that gets data from a JSON link and populates a dropdown based on that data. My question is, currently anyone can access the URL where the json is getting printed to and I want to secure it so that only the server and the pages running on the server can access the JSON output.

I was thinking of comparing PHP server vars such as remote_addr and server_addr but the remote_addr is the clients IP and not the server.

What is a good way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: In short: not possible.

Comment: How are you authenticating/authorizing the users in the first place?  If there is an authentication cookie, I would imagine that cookie would be included in the AJAX request as well, correct?  You'd verify based on that.

Comment: Don't expose your API publicly at all. Forget about doing this with PHP code; keep the ports and routes closed at the firewall/DNS/infrastructure level.

Comment: There may be some confusion on the responses here... Define "the pages running on the server."  Do your client-side users make requests from their browsers for this data?  Or is it truly _only_ ever accessed server-side?  Please give more information and ideally a small code sample showing what you mean.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Guys, I think you may have misunderstood the question; I think he's trying to prevent JSON hijacking - where another site embeds your JSON file in a script tag and then gets the data from it using custom object setters. It _is_ entirely possible (and trivial) to prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

The security issue you refer to is known as [JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx), and whilst some browsers now include [features to mitigate the risk](http://ejohn.org/blog/re-securing-json/), it is still an issue in other browsers.

Fortunately there is a fairly simple solution. To understand it, we need to understand how the attack works in the first place.
It isn't actually possible for a third-party site to simply request your JSON file via an XMLHTTPRequest and parse it in the normal way, as this would be prevented by the same-origin policy.
So what the attacker does is redefine the object setter functions in JavaScript to return the values of any new objects to his own code, and then create a new `<script>` tag referencing your JSON file. When the JSON is loaded the browser will execute it, create a new object, and return the values to the attacker's object setter handler. The attacker now has your data.

To prevent this, what you need to do is make it impossible to parse the JSON code directly as JavaScript. You want to make it throw an error if this is done.
One common way to achieve this (used by sites such as Google and Facebook) is to add code to  the beginning of the JSON file which will create an infinite loop, preventing the parser from reaching the rest of the code (and throwing a JavaScript error).

For example, Facebook's JSON responses start with the string `for(;;);`, while Google use various bits of code such as `while(1);`, and `throw(1); <don't be evil>` (the latter simply throws an error directly, rather than creating an infinite loop).

You will also then need to modify your own JSON handling JavaScript to strip this cruft out before parsing it. For example, you might do:

```
function parseJSON(json) {
   json = json.replace("for(;;);", "");
   /* parse your JSON as usual */
}
```

This adds a little bit of cruft to your script and your JSON, but is effective at preventing JSON hijacking.